# Incompatible dimensions problem with Keras

Tags: numpy, keras

I have this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

But my input layer of my keras model is

```
model.add(Dense(units = 5, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 6 ))
```

so (6,) dimension and the input is

```
inputs = np.array([HeadX, HeadY, TailX, TailY, AppleX, AppleY], float)
```

When I try to test my model with this input I have the error.
And when I try `inputs.shape` I have (6,) so I don't understand.

Comment: This confusion often arises when there's a single input being provided to the network - explicitly reshaping your input array to (6, 1) by using `np.reshape()` should work.

Comment: I try to use the function reshape :
inputs = np.reshape(inputs, (6,1))
But it don't work

Comment: Can you tell me what error message you get?

Comment: The same error : ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution, thank you k-venkatesan!

I tried with the reshape but it didn't work so i had to simply create the numpy array:

```
inputs = np.array([[HeadX, HeadY, TailX, TailY, AppleX, AppleY]], float)
```

The input is unique so i had to put it in an python array.